# Why do we use '%04.3f' in Python?

Tags: python, string-formatting

I have come across the following code.

```
print ('%04.3f' % random.uniform(1, 100))
```

What does `'%04.3f'` represent in the code?

Comment: [DOCUMENT](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-formatting)

Comment: see https://pyformat.info/

Comment: It is used to have at least 4 characters with 3 after the decimal point.

Answer (score 6):

The format specifiers for most languages are derived from the [c](/questions/tagged/c) language.

You can reference the full format [list here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

---

The format `%04.3f` specifies:

- `%f` => float value precision
- `%.3f` => float value with 3 decimal precision
- `%04.3f` => float value, with 3 decimal precision and 4 digits to the left of decimal. The `04` implies that the number will be padded with `0`s if the value is less than `1000`.